# Create a Django model based on a JOIN query

Tags: sql, django, model, django-queryset

My searches for this topic led to answers about using sql to work with the data from models, but what I want to do is effectively create something that behaves like a model to the rest of django but is based on a custom query including a JOIN.

In Microsoft Access forms and reports can be based on a queryset just as easily as on a table, and at least some of the time those recordsets can be updatable.

I'd like to be able to use all of the power of django but with the underlying models able to be based on queries. Can that be done?

Comment: Creating a model that can read from a database view is easy - if that covers your needs I can show you how to do that. Creating a model that can write to a database view would require that your database back end accept writes to a view, and I am not aware of any database back ends that support that. There might be one I'm not aware of, I suppose.

Comment: If necessary I can write the code that does the updates, deletes or inserts. I'm using postgresql so I think I can create trigger functions on a view that will activate on an attempt to update the columns of the view that I need to modify. I've never tried that but I think it's possible. However that would hide the implementation in the database, possibly in python, and not in django where it should be in the models.py

Comment: If I'm to put the code in the model then I guess I need: 1) a function that gets run every time django would execute the SELECT query. 2) a way to make my special model fields return the column values when used. 3) a way to intercept and implement updates to individual values or some overall intercept of any operations that would write to the database. I would also need to mimic the right exceptions for operations that I don't implement on fields

Comment: Django uses its database back end packages to turn model updates into SQL, so conceptually speaking the right place to put custom translations of model changes into SQL would be to write your own database back end. That's a bit lower level than I've ever had to go, so I'm not sure about whether there are any shortcuts possible to keep it reasonable.

Comment: If I set managed = False doesn't that mean that I inhibit the implicit database operations and instead have to initiate them myself?

Comment: If you were to write such a back end you wouldn't use managed=False.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you declare the model as unmanaged by django. But you will have to create the SQL code for the tables/views on your own.

```
class SQLView(models.Model):

    # your field definitions

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'your_view_name'
```

With postgresql as database you can create views and rules or triggers that intercept operations.

Comment: How do I intercept attempts to change fields or to insert or delete records?

Comment: I am using postgresql, but I'd prefer to put the implementation in the model rather than in the database.